# Prevent .replace from replacing already replaced letters

Tags: javascript, replace

As a practice, I'm trying to create a fake 'translator' that will convert english to a jumbled version of the alphabet using .replace, however I'm having a problem that the .replace action replaces letters that have been previously replaced.

Is there a way for me to prevent the code re-replacing letters that have already been replaced?

My HTML:

```
<button onclick="Function()">click</button>

<p id="let">a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>

<p id="demor"></p>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function Function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("let").innerHTML;
    var txt = str.replace(/a/g,"x").replace(/b/g,"b").replace(/c/g,"c").replace(/d/g,"d").replace(/e/g,"a").replace(/f/g,"k").replace(/g/g,"s").replace(/h/g,"r").replace(/i/g,"e").replace(/j/g,"i").replace(/k/g,"d").replace(/l/g,"r").replace(/m/g,"z").replace(/n/g,"m").replace(/o/g,"s").replace(/p/g,"v").replace(/q/g,"p").replace(/r/g,"r").replace(/s/g,"k").replace(/t/g,"s").replace(/u/g,"i").replace(/v/g,"q").replace(/w/g,"v").replace(/x/g,"x").replace(/y/g,"e").replace(/z/g,"b");
    document.getElementById("demor").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create an object and use a key value pair to determine what should be what instead of doing `.replace` so many times :s

Comment: Here is a rendition of 'Jonas w's code below applied with some handy 'pseduo loc' alphabet replacements: https://jsfiddle.net/7snz7n4f/

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly inefficient, but should get the general idea across - basically you split the string so it's an array of characters, then run the replace on each character:

```
var map = { a: 'x', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', e: 'a', f: 'k', g: 's', h: 'r', i: 'e', j: 'i', k: 'd', l: 'r', m: 'z', n: 'm', o: 's', p: 'v', q: 'p', r: 'r', s: 'k', t: 's', u: 'i', v: 'q', w: 'v', x: 'x', y: 'e', z: 'b' };

function Function() {
    var str = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
    var txt = str.split('').map(function(c) { 
        return map[c]; 
    }).join('');
    console.log(txt);
}
```

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem. The user doesnt want that a replaced letter is replaced again : a-> x-> b -> e or sth like that

Comment: @Jonasw This does solve that problem.  Unless you misunderstand the problem?  He wants to change f -> k for example, and then when it gets to k (which was an f originally), he doesn't want it changed again since it was already replaced.  Each character should be replaced only once.  This solves that.

Comment: but doesnt your code replace the g in str with x, replace the g in b with that result... and so in fact doing the same??

Comment: @Jonasw Ah, I see what you are saying, yeah which is why I had the note at the bottom that he'll need to have a map of the characters.  I'll update to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would go in different way - create numbers which will be represantation of letters.

Example structure:

```
var nums={
  1:"a",
  2:"b",
  3:"c",
  4:"d"
...//rest
}
```

Next change orginal text to numbers:

```
str.replace(/a/g,"1").replace(/b/g,"2") ...
```

Last is to do the second replace but to final letters

```
str.replace(/1/g,nums[1]).replace(/2/g,nums[2]) ...
```

So we are sure that change will be not overrided. My js code in answer is pseudo-code, I wanted only to show the idea. Most important is that numbers should be like identificators, so must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will scan through the whole string once for each replace. Much better to go char by char, performing the translation on each one in turn.

This is a quick-and-dirty version, cut down to only cover lower case letters -- you can tidy it up and make it cover whatever range of characters you like:

```
var input = "helloworld";
var xlate = "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza";
var asciiA = 'a'.charCodeAt();

var out = "";
for(i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
    out = out + xlate[input[i].charCodeAt() - asciiA];
}

alert(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think that cant be done with replace, thats how i would do that:

```
//create translation arrays
var letters=["a","b",...];
var replacewith=["x","b",...];

//move the string to an array
var string="abc";
var arr=string.split("");
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
for(o=0;o<letters.length;o++){
if(arr[i]==letters[o]){
//replace
arr[i]=replacewith[o];
//stop replacing
break;
}
}
}
string=arr.join("");
```

String is replaced with the characters...

Answer (score 0):

With my [replace-once](https://github.com/kodie/replace-once) package, you could do the following:

```
const replaceOnce = require('replace-once')

var str = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z'
var find = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
var replace = 'xbcdaksreidrzmsvprksiqvxeb'
replaceOnce(str, find.split(''), replace.split(''), 'gi')
//=> 'x b c d a k s r e i d r z m s v p r k s i q v x e b'
```